# Kubernetes API - gets list of Nodes hosting specific deployment/pods

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Say I have a 5 node cluster of kafka and a kubernetes cluster of 100 nodes.

Now, I want to find all 5 nodes (of 100) which is hosting kafka pod. So something like:

```
kubectl get nodes --selector="deployment.kafka"
```

Comment: I doubt that is possible since the node should have the labels for above to work. you can use the `-o wide` option though as `kubectl get pods --selector="deployment.kafka" -o wide | awk '{print $7}'` (column number could be different depending on the output of `kubectl get pod` command. Note: this assumes that the pod has the labels `deployment.kafka` set on them.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think thats possible, what you can do is select your pods based on labels and get the node name, As @Krishna said in his comment, so the command will be

```
kubectl get pods -n NAMESPACE_NAME -l app=kafka  -o wide | awk '{print $7}'
```

`app=kafka` is the label on the pods, it might be different in your case